# Filter specific Values from a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, filter

I would like to build a python3 script that will download a CSV file every day and send it to me by mail.
I have managed to download the file and sending the mail. The problem is the filtering. The CSV file contains

```
"155;03155;Northeim;1669;1261.7;9;35;0;131.55;66;49.9"
```

and I want to filter only the last value `49.9` and send it to me by mail. This Value changes daily. But the order of the values doesn't.

Can someone help me?

Comment: does your CSV file only have 1 row or multiple rows?

Comment: for multiple rows I would use pandas df.iloc[:, -1]

Comment: I'd just use `csv.reader` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html - set your delimiter to ";", and take field `[10]`

Comment: @vishal Singh It only has 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CSV file only contains 1 row then read the file, split at `;` and access the last element of the list using `[-1]`.

```
with open('your_csv_file.csv') as fp:
    value = fp.read().split(';')[-1]
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked perfectly :)